# Heathrow: do I need to go through immigration in the terminal I arrived at?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, tips-and-tricks, lhr

Yesterday I arrived at Heathrow terminal 4 and waited 2:30 in line for immigration. I noticed that there was corridor which said "transfer to terminals 2/3" (I'm guessing for flight transfers). While in line I was wondering if it's possible to transfer to another terminal and go through immigration there. I assumed that it couldn't get any worse than the line I was in.

Edit: I had only hand luggage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No you don't. You can transfer to other terminals and exit there. However, you must be travelling with *hand luggage only*, otherwise you will have to return to the original terminal land-side to collect your luggage, which would be difficult as you would need to get past customs to collect it.

Here's an [explanatory post](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/25935806-post10.html) on flytalk.

> One of the quirks of the airside transfer buses and the flight
>   connection areas in each terminal is that you can arrive on an INT
>   flight at T5 but cross the UK border at another terminal. In fact you
>   can also do this in reverse, so arrive on an INT at T3 for example,
>   and cross the UK border at T5. Whilst this is not really recommended
>   normally, you may wish to do this if you have your car or left luggage
>   at another terminal or you find the UK border at the terminal you
>   arrive at to be very busy.

Comment: If you have hand luggage only then it should be no problem.